# How to copy the data of an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy

I'm trying to copy the data present in an array of pointers to another one.

I have very few knowledge in C++, but some in higher level languages.

Here is a sample code of what I've achieved so far (simplified version):

```cpp
#define MAX_ACTIVE_MODES 3

myStruct_t priorities1[MAX_ACTIVE_MODES];

myStruct_t *priorities2[MAX_ACTIVE_MODES];

for (unsigned short i = 0; i < MAX_ACTIVE_MODES; ++i) {
   priorities2[i] = (myStruct_t*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct_t));

   memcpy(priorities2[i], &priorities1[i], sizeof(myStruct_t));
}

// ...

delete[] *priorities2;
```

It's easier for me to have a non pointer var for `priorities1` and have one for `priorities2` because I'm passing it to a sort function.

When I search for solutions, there's never the case of `type *var[]` and I don't get why.

Comment: What's working and what is not ? Except the `delete`, this really is C style code, why not use C++ `std::array` ?

Comment: You do something strange in delete[] *priorities; and priorities2[i] = (myStruct_t*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct_t)); use new in C++

Comment: @Andrey, No! never use `new` in c++. Use smart pointers or container classes instead.

Comment: @HAL9000 yes, use RAII, but in education task new is way to learn pointers and mem alloc

Comment: Is your code broken? What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: @Andrey, When learning about pointers and mem alloc, I agree, you are forced to use `new` / `malloc`. But any recomendation to use `new` must come with a warning, **Only for educational purpose**

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 It's compiling, but I have memory leak and in debug mode I have bad memory access so I guess it's not the right way.

Comment: @LucasGras I can't, I'm compiling on a microcontroller so there's not the standard lib

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I assume that you are programming in C based on your use of `malloc`.

First you don't need to use `memcpy` to copy structs.

```
*priorities2[i] = priorities1[i];
```

should be equivalent to

```
memcpy(priorities2[i], &priorities1[i], sizeof(myStruct_t));
```

Second, you don't have to create copies of the elements in  `priorities1[]`. Just have the pointers in `priorities2[]` point to the elements in `priorities1[]`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_ACTIVE_MODES; ++i) 
  {
     priorities2[i] = &priorities1[i];
  }
```

As long as you don't access `priorities2` beyond the lifetime of `priorities1`, no `malloc` or `free` is needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The thing is I'm making a copy because I don't want the original struct to be modified if I make changes in the copied one. So it's not working.